# Iterate over a dictionary and return all the keys and values in an updated form using multiprocessing module in python

Tags: python, dictionary, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, nested-function

I have a data structure like '*motif*' initially :

*motif* = { '1S-2C,2C-2C' :[ [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]] ],'1S-1S,1S-2C': [ [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]] ]}*

I would like to create a subprocess for each key and  pass it into some function called '*extension()*'. The updations to each element is done at '*modify()*'.

The problem with the below snippet :I am getting the output like this '*returnMotif*' : {'1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E':[[[1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0]], [[3, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]], [[4, 6], [6, 6], [0, 0]]],'1S-1S,1S-2C,3O-3O': [ [[1,1],[1,2],[0,0]], [[3,3],[3,5],[0,0]] ]}  .i.e., they exactly fall in the same place from where they called without looking at the keys. But I want 'returnMotif' be like:

*returnMotif* = { '1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E' : [ [[1,2],[2,2],[0,0]], [[4,6],[6,6],[0,0]] ], '1S-1S,2C-2C,3O-3O' : [  [[3,5],[5,5],[0,0]] ], '1S-1S,1S-2C,3E-3E' : [ [[1,1],[1,2],[0,0]]], '1S-1S,1S-2C,3O-3O' : [  [[3,3],[3,5],[0,0]] ]}
  So, How can I iterate over '*motif*' dictionary using multiprocessing module and get all the updated elements in '*returnMotif*' at main()?

I have a patch like this: Can anyone make any modification on this?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager
from collections import defaultdict

def modify(x,i):
    #print i[1][1]
    if i[1][1] % 2 == 0:    
        return x+',3E-3E' #last element is even
    else:
        return x+',3O-3O'# last element is odd

def extension(x):  # Function that is called during multiprocessing.
    # do some function on each element like  [[1,2],[2,2]],[[3,5],5,5]], [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]]. Let it be the function 'modify()'
    #print x # should have the key
    #print motif[x] # clearly has the value
    allTemps=[]
    for i in motif[x]:
        #print i
        (newX) = modify(x, i)
        i.append([0,0])
        allTemps.append(i)
    return (newX,allTemps)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Dictionary with list of list of parameters:

    motif={'1S-2C,2C-2C':[ [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]] ]}

    p = Pool(4)  # Setting up the number of CPU's to use.

    returnMotif = dict( p.map( extension , motif.keys() ) )

    p.close()
    p.join()

# when I return the modified keys and values, they exactly fall in the same place from where they called without looking at the keys ie, [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]] these 3 elements have the same key '1S-2C,2C-2C'. But in the modified key-value pairs, only two of them have same key and the third one is having a different key. ie, [[1,2],[2,2],[0,0]] ,  [[4,6],[6,6],[0,0]] these two elements have a key of  '1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E' and  [[3,5],[5,5],[0,0]] has a key of  '1S-2C,2C-2C,3O-3O'. But it's coming like this: ** returnMotif ** 1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E     [[[1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0]], [[3, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]], [[4, 6], [6, 6], [0, 0]]] 
#I want it to be split into two key-value pair like format below :{'1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E':[[[1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0]],  [[4, 6], [6, 6], [0, 0]]] ,'1S-2C,2C-2C,3O-3O':[ [[3, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]] ]}



print "**  Return Motifs:\n"
for i in returnMotif:
    print i,"\t",returnMotif[i],"\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick Proof-o'-Concept that I ran:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

m = {
  'a': [ 1,2 ] ,
  'b': [ 3,4 ] ,
  'c': [ 5,6 ] ,
}

def f(x):
    return (x,m[x][0] + m[x][1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, m.keys() ))
```

The program above ( as you can see, it's a derivative work from the example given in the [16.6 multiprocessing page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)   )  will add the numbers in the simple lists in my example dictionary, m, to yield this result:

```
[('a', 3), ('c', 11), ('b', 7)]
```

In general, I'm suggesting that if you simplify your use of the multiprocessing module to use map instead of apply_async, you'll have an easier time of it.

Connecting the dots, here's a snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager

def extension(x):  # Function that is called during multiprocessing.
    # do some function on each element like  [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]]
    # ** MISTAKE : Not getting elements here for processing along with it's corresponding key **
    #print x,"\t\n"
    #print x # should have the key
    #print motif[x] # clearly has the value
    return (x,motif[x])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Dictionary with list of list of parameters:
    motif={'1S-2C,2C-2C':[ [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]] ],'1S-1S,1S-2C': [ [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]] ] }
    p = Pool(4)  # Setting up the number of CPU's to use.

    returnMotif = dict( p.map( extension , motif.keys() ) )

    p.close()
    p.join()

    print returnMotif
```

A caveat:  it's not clear to me that read-only access to the dictionary motif is thread safe.  In a java application I once wrote, the HashMap I used was updated every time it was read, since it maintained a linked list to track least recently used.

Ok, a second caveat:  The code in the extension function must absolutely not modify the motif dictionary.  Keys should not be added or removed for certain.

Based on ANJALY's recent comment (March 25 2017), here is an updated code snippet to get the desired behavior.  It really has nothing to do with asynchronous processing, so I'm going to leave the code above and post a new snippet here below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool,Manager
def modify(x,i):
    i.append([0,0])
    modX = x+',3S-3S'
    #print modX,"\t",i,"\n**\n"
    return (modX,i)

def extension(x):  # Function that is called during multiprocessing.
    # do some function on each element like  [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],5,5]], [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]]. Let it be the function 'modify()'
    #print x # should have the key
    #print motif[x] # clearly has the value
    alltemps=[]
    for  i in motif[x]:
        (newX,temp) = modify(x,i)
        alltemps.append(temp)
    return (newX,alltemps)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Dictionary with list of list of parameters:

    motif={'1S-2C,2C-2C':[ [[1,2],[2,2]], [[3,5],[5,5]], [[4,6],[6,6]] ],'1S-1S,1S-2C': [ [[1,1],[1,2]], [[3,3],[3,5]] ] }
    p = Pool(4)  # Setting up the number of CPU's to use.

    returnMotif = dict( p.map( extension , motif.keys() ) )

    p.close()
    p.join()
print returnMotif
```

In the code above, I added a local variable ( very important that the variable is local in a multi processing environment ) to collect the results.  I also moved the return statement  out of the loop ( I out-dented it ) .

Comment: The snippet given above takes keys and values properly. But only the  last element of each key is getting modified and entered to  'returnMotif' .But I want all the element get updated and  'returnMotif' be like    'returnMotif'={'1S-2C,2C-2C,3S-3S':[ [[1,2],[2,2],[0,0]], [[3,5],[5,5],[0,0]], [[4,6],[6,6],[0,0]] ],'1S-1S,1S-2C,3S-3S': [ [[1,1],[1,2],[0,0]], [[3,3],[3,5],[0,0]] ] }

Comment: if returned values are not having same key, how can I update the returnMotif with new key-value pair..ie,Now returnMotif{'1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E':[[[1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0]], [[3, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]], [[4, 6], [6, 6], [0, 0]]]. I want it to be split into two key-value pair like format below :
'1S-2C,2C-2C,3E-3E':{ [[[1, 2], [2, 2], [0, 0]],  [[4, 6], [6, 6], [0, 0]]] }
'1S-2C,2C-2C,3O-3O': { [[3, 5], [5, 5], [0, 0]] }